Can I set the path for a markdown image in configuration using League\CommonMark?
I'm using the GitHub-Flavored Markdown environment with the PHP League's markdown package (CommonMark). The library is applying the URL and a path to image markdown in Markdown files that is incorrect. I've read the configuration documents and can't find an option to change the root path. I'd rather set the option in configuration than apply a regex on the outputted HTML.
Does League\CommonMark have an option for setting the base URL of image markdown markup (not the filename that's passed in the markdown markup)?
